# how to specify number in querySelectorAll regex

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I work with tree of checkboxes and I play with their visibily status.
Here is a simple tree of 3 checkboxes

```
<div id="d1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1"  onclick="gestion('1')" >
    <label>1</label>
</div>
<div id="d1.1" class="initialHide">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1" onclick="gestion('1.1')">
    <label>1.1</label>
</div>
<div id="d1.1.1" class="initialHide">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1.1" onclick="gestion('1.1.1')">
    <label>1.1.1</label>
</div>
```

and here is the beginning of my script

```
function gestion(id){
    var rechercheDiv='[id^="d'+id+'."]';
    var listDiv = document.querySelectorAll(rechercheDiv)
```

Here is my problem : I want to select only the children div of the div of the current checkbox. d1 has only d1.1 as direct children.
But my regex used in querySelectorAll return all children div.

Is there a way to modify my regex to get only the direct children?
The pseudo code is starts with d then the id then . then numbers then nothing else.
Ex : given d1  d1.1 is a children and d1.1.1 is not a children.

Comment: You are not using regex, these a css selectors.

Comment: `d1.1` is not direct children

Comment: "Child" is a defined meaning in HTML and CSS. "Direct child" doesn't and checkboxes can't have children. What are you really looking for?

Comment: sorry for the use of term child which can be confusing. When I check checkbox c1 I want to show div d1.1. When I check checkbox  c1.1 i want to show div d1.1.1. When I uncheck checkbox c1 I want to hide both div d1.1 and d1.1.1. Etc. It is the logic of a tree of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

If the element you want always comes after the one with the `id` you pass to the function, you can use an [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to select and replace [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
function getCheckbox(id){
  return document.querySelector(`[id="d${ id }"] + [id^="d${ id }."]`);
}

document.onchange = (e) => {
  console.log(getCheckbox(e.target.id.substring(1)));
};

console.log(getCheckbox('1'));
console.log(getCheckbox('1.1'));
console.log(getCheckbox('1.1.1'));
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 67px !important;
}
```

```html
<label id="d1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
  1
</label>

<label id="d1.1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1" />
  1.1
</label>

<label id="d1.1.1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1.1" />
  1.1.1
</label>
```

If that's not the case, and you might have some other elements between the, you could so something like this using a [general sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) instead:

```js
function getCheckbox(id) {
  return document.querySelector(`[id="d${ id }"] ~ [id^="d${ id }."]`)
}

document.onchange = (e) => {
  console.log(getCheckbox(e.target.id.substring(1)));
};

console.log(getCheckbox('1'));
console.log(getCheckbox('1.1'));
console.log(getCheckbox('1.1.1'));
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 67px !important;
}
```

```html
<label id="d1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
  1
</label>

<span></span>

<label id="d1.1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1" />
  1.1
</label>

<span></span>

<label id="d1.1.1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1.1.1" />
  1.1.1
</label>
```